# Show that an operator is invertible and the inequality is satisfied.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let V, W be two Banach spaces and the equation $Lv=w$ has solutions in V for all $w\in W$, where $L\in \mathcal{L}( V, W)$. Moreover, there exists a positive constant C such that
$$\|Lv\|\geq C\|v\|,~~~~\forall v\in V.$$

Show that L is invertible and $\|L^{-1}\|\leq \dfrac{1}{C}$.

Comment: Would $L$ be a functional or an operator?  In general, functionals are not invertible because they have a range of dimension 1, so their kernel has nonzero dimension (for a given definition of dimension).

Comment: My bad! It is an operator.

Comment: Great! So what have you tried?  Hint: consider what can be in the kernel in light of the inequality given.  This will help with proving invertibility.

Comment: I have no clue to prove it is invertible. I wanna try open mapping theorem, but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: I don't think you need that here - an operator is invertible iff it only has zero in its kernel.  Does an operator satisfying the inequality have nonzero things in its kernel?

Comment: I will try this! Thank you for your hint!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got both parts:

Invertibility follows since if there is some $w \neq 0$ such that $Lw = 0$, then $\|Lw \| = 0$ but $\|w\| \neq 0$, which contradicts the given inequality.  To show the bound, write the definition of the operator norm:

$$
\| L^{-1} \| = \sup_{v \neq 0} \frac{\|L^{-1}v\|}{\|v\|} = \sup_{Lw \neq 0} \frac{\|L^{-1}(Lw)\|}{\|Lw\|} = \sup_{Lw \neq 0} \frac{\|w\|}{\|Lw\|} \leq \sup_{Lw \neq 0} \frac{1}{C} = \frac{1}{C}. 
$$

The only trick is to notice that we can write any $v$ in the range of $L$ as $v = Lw$ (by definition).  Then we just crank away until we can apply the given inequality to get the inverse bound.